# Why doesn't python pyinstaller work with my Python 3.7.0 file?

Tags: command-line, pyinstaller, python-3.7

I have Python 3.7.0 installed and I tried to use pyinstaller to make my .py file into .exe file. However, when I run my .exe file, it doesn't work.

[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Graha.png)

How do I fix this error?